# How can I easily append data from checkboxes in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to append HTML/data to div when the checkboxes is checked. I also want to know the best practices to how append data/html easily from the checkboxes.

However, please see the code below:

Ajax

```
 $('.myCheck').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getCategoryItems',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            name: $(this).attr("name")
        },
        success: function (data) {
            setTimeout(function () {


            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```

View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Cars)
  {
                <span class="label">
                    @item.CategoryName <span class="badge">@item.CategoryCount</span>
                </span>
                            @Html.CheckBox(item.CategoryName, new { @class = "myCheck", })
                            @Html.Hidden("name", item.CategoryName, new { id = item.CategoryId })
}




Controller:

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult getCategoryItems(string name)
    {
        var select = (from r in _db.Cars             
                      where r.Category.Name == name
                      select new
                      {
                          r.Title,
                          r.Price,
                          r.FileName,
                          r.Category.Name,
                          r.City,
                          r.TagName,
                          r.Id,
                          }).ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = select, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

This is what I want to append:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="container" id="sek1">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12 no-padding-lr sear-result-column">
                    <div class="latest-job article-row1">
                        <div class="col-md-2 no-padding-lr resp-grid1 box-sadow">
                            <img src="https://wp-themes.com/wp-content/themes/jobile/images/no-image.jpg" width="100" height="86">

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-10 no-padding-lr">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 no-padding-lr job-status resp-grid1 job-status-3">

                                <h3>@item.Title</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 job-status resp-grid1 job-status-3">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="LesMerBtn">@item.Price</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding-lr">
                                <div class="job-btn-group late-job-btn clearfix">

                                    <a href="" rel="category" class="person-post"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>@item.City</a>

                            <a href="" rel="category" class="person-post"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>Kategori: @item.CategoryName</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding-lr">
                        <p class="result-btm-text"></p><p>Test....</p>
                        <a href="" class="color-068587"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" id="eye-open"></span>Read more</a><p></p>

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, "ifChecked" is not a valid event. You are going to be looking at the change event on the checkbox and then checking if $(this).is(":checked") for checkbox state. Note that the state changes BEFORE it enters your function, so when the checkbox gets checked, .is(":checked") will return true, and vis-versa

Comment: @mhodges Thanks for your answer. I'm using ICheck.js for styling the checkboxes, it's why I have ifChecked there. Anyway,  it looks fine. I get the correct data in console, but I just need to find a way to append data/html to div when the checkboxes is checked..

Comment: What data you want to append  ? To which div ?

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I was going to mention it's not a standard event, but if you are using a library it could be valid. Thanks for the clarification, I better understand your question now

Comment: I'm assuming you want to return the list of cars returned by each category checkbox? And I do not see any divs in your view, did you want to create a div next to the checkbox that was checked as a container for the results?

Comment: @Shyju I just updated my post. Please see the html that I want to append.

Comment: @mhodges I just updated my post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the json response in your `success` event of your ajax call. The response is of an array and you need to iterate through the array and get each item in the array, read the property values and use that to build your html markup you want to append.

```
success: function (data) {
   var myHtml="";
   $.each(data,function(a,b){
                               myHtml+="<div><p>"+b.Title+"</p>";
                               myHtml+="<p>"+b.City+"</p>";
                               myHtml+="<p>"+b.Price+"</p></div>";
   });
   $("#YourDivId").append(myHtml);
}
```

Assuming YourDivId is the Id of the Div where you want to show the data coming from your ajax call and this div exists in your page.

This works if you are making simple html markup. But if you have some complicated markup you want to appen/show. i recommend returning a partial view from your ajax call.

So in your action method, instead of returning the json data, pass that data to your partial view and let the action method returns the razor generated html markup with the data.

Assuming you have a view model like this to represent a Car

```
public class CarVm
{
  public string Title { set;get;}
  public decimal Amount { set;get;}
  public string City { set;get;}
}
```

In your action method, create a list of `CarVm` from the data from your db table and pass that to the partial view.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult getCategoryItems(string name)
{
    var carVmList= (from r in _db.Cars             
                  where r.Category.Name == name
                  select new CarVm { Title =r.Title,
                                     City =r.City,
                                     Price=r.Price
                                   }
                 ).ToList();
    return PartiaView("CarsPerCategory",carVmList);
}
```

Assuming you have a partial view called `CarsPerCategory.cshtml` which is strongly typed to a collection of `CarVm` type. The partial view should exist in either `~/Views/Shared/` or `~/Views/YourCurrentControllerName/`

```
@model List<CarVm>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.Title</p>
  <!-- Add the remaining markup you want (same as the code in your question) -->
}
```

And in your success event you simply append the response coming back to your container div.

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#YourDivId").append(data);
}
```

you may use `append()` method or `html()` method depending on you want to replace the existing value or just append it.

Comment: Thank you so much Shyju! it worked as I expected. I also learned something new! Again Thanks! :)